# Changing language with angular-translate causes error with messageformat and binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate, messageformat.js

I am trying to learn angular-translate using messageformat.
When I click my button to change language, i get an error 'undefined is not a function' - but it's not 100% reliable. It happens very easily, but I am not sure which change triggers the error.

Reproduced by: 
Tested in Chrome 41 Firefox developer edition 39 and IE11 also. Does not work.

Here is how I reproduced it in detail:
On fresh load:
Set variable to another number (eg. 3) while still English.
Change to Norwegian. Change number to something else.
Change back to English. When I try to change the number now, it doesn't work anymore
I have recreated my code in a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/K4xHNf93Vhkrfc5LmliV?p=preview

The code is the following:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="Controller as Ctrl">
    <h1>{{ 'TITLE' | translate }}</h1>
    <p>{{ 'FOO' | translate }}</p>
    <input type="number" ng-model="translationData.NUM">
    <p>{{ 'PLURAL' | translate:translationData}}</p>
    <button ng-click="changeLanguage('en')">{{ 'BUTTON_LANG_EN' | translate}}</button>
    <button ng-click="changeLanguage('de')">{{ 'BUTTON_LANG_DE' | translate}}</button>
    <button ng-click="changeLanguage('no')">{{ 'BUTTON_LANG_NO' | translate}}</button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module('app', ['pascalprecht.translate'])
.config(function ($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider.translations('en', {
        TITLE: 'Hello',
        FOO: 'This is a paragraph.',
        BUTTON_LANG_EN: 'English',
        BUTTON_LANG_DE: 'German',
        BUTTON_LANG_NO: 'Norwegian',
        PLURAL: "You have {NUM, plural, =0{no messages} one{1 message} other{# messages}}."
    });
    $translateProvider.translations('de', {
        TITLE: 'Hallo',
        FOO: 'Dies ist ein Paragraph.',
        BUTTON_LANG_EN: 'Englisch',
        BUTTON_LANG_DE: 'Deutsch',
        BUTTON_LANG_NO: 'Norwegisch',
        PLURAL: "Sie haben {NUM, plural, =0{keine Nachrichten haben} one{1 Nachricht} other{# Nachrichten}}."
    });
    $translateProvider.translations('no', {
        TITLE: 'Hei',
        FOO: 'Dette er en paragraf',
        BUTTON_LANG_EN: 'Engelsk',
        BUTTON_LANG_DE: 'Tysk',
        BUTTON_LANG_NO: 'Norsk',
        PLURAL: "Du har {NUM, plural, =0{ingen meldinger} one{1 melding} other{# meldinger}}."
    });
    $translateProvider.useMessageFormatInterpolation();
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
    $translateProvider.fallbackLanguage('en');

})
.controller('Controller', function ($scope, $translate) {
    $scope.translationData = {
        NUM: 0
    };
    $scope.changeLanguage = function (key) {
        $translate.use(key);
    };
});
```

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Comment: I have run the plunker which you have provided it's working fine...

Comment: Try to change the number variable, then change languages a couple of times and change the number each time also. For me it stops working and there are errors in the console (running locally it says undefined in the output, but in the plunker the bound doesnt work anymore)

Comment: Still works. Which browser are u using?

Comment: Chrome 41. Tested in Firefox and IE also. Does not work.

Here is how I reproduced it in detail:
On fresh load:
Set variable to another number (eg. 3) while still English.
Change to Norwegian. Change number to something else.
Change back to English. When I try to change the number now, it doesn't work anymore

Comment: I ran the plunker. Looks like you need to have "make-plural" also for message-format to pluralize. I get a different error

`TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at MessageFormat.runtime.plural (http://run.plnkr.co/dOcNRGwLQX9scW7v/messageformat.js:1549:15)`